# Having problems making a max-min priority queue(python)

Tags: python

I made a min-max priority queue in python. I tested it using my example and had no problems, but the coding website(a site like leetcode) said that the output was wrong(Not an error)... Is there any problems / improvements I can make?

I think there is a import that I can make to make this part easier(I think), but I'm trying to get the concept right before importing it in the future.

```
class MaxMinHeap:
    def __init__(self, max_len):
        self.heap_arr = [0 for _ in range(max_len + 1)]
        self.arr_len = 0

    # checks if heap is empty
    def empty(self):
        if self.arr_len == 0:
            return True
        return False

    # checks if the level of the tree is an odd number or an even number
    def is_min_level(self):
        if math.floor(math.log2(self.arr_len)) % 2 == 1:
            return False
        return True

    # inserts a number to the heap
    def insert_num(self, input_num):
        self.arr_len += 1
        self.heap_arr[self.arr_len] = input_num
        # if the array was empty, don't do any checks
        if self.arr_len == 1:
            return
        # else if the array is at the min level of the tree
        elif self.is_min_level():
            self.min_insert()
        else:
            self.max_insert()

    # when a number is added to the heap at the max level
    def max_insert(self):
        # if the child is bigger than the number
        if self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2] > self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]:
            # change the values
            self.heap_arr[self.arr_len], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2] = self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]
            # keep updating the values up the min tree
            self.minify_up(self.arr_len // 2)
        else:
            # keep updating the values up the max tree
            self.maxity_up(self.arr_len)

    # when a number is added to the heap at the min level
    def min_insert(self):
        # if the child is smaller than the number
        if self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2] < self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]:
            # change the values
            self.heap_arr[self.arr_len], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2] = self.heap_arr[self.arr_len // 2], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]
            # keep updating the values up the max tree
            self.maxity_up(self.arr_len // 2)
        else:
            # keep updating the values up the min tree
            self.minify_up(self.arr_len)

    # when a max number is needed
    def max_output(self):
        if self.empty():
            return -1
        # if there is only one number(the first node is in the min level) return that node
        if self.arr_len == 1:
            self.arr_len -= 1
            return self.heap_arr[1]
        # else check the second and third node to get max num
        temp_index = 2
        if temp_index + 1 <= self.arr_len and self.heap_arr[temp_index] < self.heap_arr[temp_index + 1]:
            temp_index += 1
        # change with the last element
        self.heap_arr[self.arr_len], self.heap_arr[temp_index] = self.heap_arr[temp_index], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]
        self.arr_len -= 1
        # go updating down the array
        self.maxify_down(temp_index)
        # print the max that was changed with the last element
        return self.heap_arr[self.arr_len + 1]

    # when a min number is needed
    def min_output(self):
        if self.empty():
            return -1
        # change with the last element(the min number is always at index 1)
        self.heap_arr[self.arr_len], self.heap_arr[1] = self.heap_arr[1], self.heap_arr[self.arr_len]
        self.arr_len -= 1
        # go updating down the array
        self.minify_down(1)
        # print the min that was changed with the last element
        return self.heap_arr[self.arr_len + 1]

    # when an output is sent from the max level
    def maxify_down(self, input_index):
        # while the node has a child
        while input_index * 2 <= self.arr_len:
            # if there are no grandchild
            if input_index * 4 > self.arr_len:
                # check the child
                comp_index = input_index * 2
                if comp_index + 1 == self.arr_len and self.heap_arr[comp_index] < self.heap_arr[comp_index]:
                    comp_index += 1
                # if any of the child are bigger change values
                if self.heap_arr[input_index] < self.heap_arr[comp_index]:
                    self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
                # end update
                return
            # else set the comparing element to its right child
            # this is because the right child might have no child. Making this node have no guarantee that it is
            # smaller than the grandchild
            comp_index = input_index * 2 + 1
            # loop through the grandchild list
            for temp_index in range(input_index * 4, input_index * 4 + 4):
                if temp_index + 1 == self.arr_len and self.heap_arr[comp_index] < self.heap_arr[temp_index]:
                    comp_index = temp_index
            # swap the max number with the index
            self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
            # if the swaped index was the child one end update
            if comp_index == input_index * 2 + 1:
                return
            # else check the parent of the node for any errors
            if self.heap_arr[comp_index] < self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2]:
                self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2]
            # set the index again and loop
            input_index = comp_index

    # when an output is sent from the max level
    def minify_down(self, input_index):
        # while the node has a child
        while input_index * 2 <= self.arr_len:
            # if there are no grandchild
            if input_index * 4 > self.arr_len:
                # check the child
                comp_index = input_index * 2
                if comp_index + 1 == self.arr_len and self.heap_arr[comp_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index]:
                    comp_index += 1
                # if any of the parents are bigger change values
                if self.heap_arr[input_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index]:
                    self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
                # end update
                return
            # else set the comparing element to its right child
            # this is because the right child might have no child. Making this node have no guarantee that it is
            # bigger than the grandchild
            comp_index = input_index * 2 + 1
            # loop through the grandchild list
            for temp_index in range(input_index * 4, input_index * 4 + 4):
                if temp_index + 1 == self.arr_len and self.heap_arr[comp_index] > self.heap_arr[temp_index]:
                    comp_index = temp_index
            # swap the min number with the index
            self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
            # if the swaped index was the child one end update
            if comp_index == input_index * 2 + 1:
                return
            # else check the parent of the node for any errors
            if self.heap_arr[comp_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2]:
                self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index // 2]
            # set the index again and loop
            input_index = comp_index

    # when input is in max level
    def maxity_up(self, input_index):
        # while the input has a grandfather
        while input_index // 4 > 0:
            # compare grandfather with input and if input is greater swap
            comp_index = input_index // 4
            if self.heap_arr[comp_index] >= self.heap_arr[input_index]:
                break
            self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index] = self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index]
            # update index and loop
            input_index = comp_index

    # when input is in min level
    def minify_up(self, input_index):
        # while the input has a grandfather
        while input_index // 4 > 0:
            # compare grandfather with input and if input is smaller swap
            comp_index = input_index // 4
            if self.heap_arr[comp_index] <= self.heap_arr[input_index]:
                break
            self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index] = self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index]
            # update index and loop
            input_index = comp_index
```

The array used to store is heap_arr and the heap starts at index 1 to make the child and parent //2 and *2 each.

I tried to look into a research paper and tried to copy its psudocode to python, but got the same results. Working for my example but not for the site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to [*"Need more focus"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486/), please edit the question to make it more focused on one specific problem or functionality. The question should isolate single problems, and have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `minify_down` (and `maxity_down`) methods have bugs. In fact, you could have found this quite easily as things already went wrong with just four values.

I'll first show a few steps you could have taken to debug this yourself:

1. Define a method that prints the heap in a human-readable "tree-view". Nothing complicated; just a 90° (counter-clockwise) rotated view where the root appears at the left and the tree extends to the right:

   ```
   def print(self, i=1, tab=""):
       if i > self.arr_len:
           return
       self.print(i*2 + 1, tab+"  ")
       print(tab, self.heap_arr[i])
       self.print(i*2, tab+"  ")
   ```
2. Define a method that verifies the consistency of the heap, and if it is not, print the heap and throw an error:

   ```
   def verify(self, i=1, ismin=True, low=-100000, high=100000):
       if i > self.arr_len:
           return
       val = self.heap_arr[i]
       if not(low <= val <= high):
           self.print()
           raise ValueError(f"inconsistent heap at {val}")
       if ismin:
           low = val
       else:
           high = val
       self.verify(i*2, not ismin, low, high)
       self.verify(i*2+1, not ismin, low, high)
   ```
3. Create some random input and feed those values to the heap, and after every call of `insert` also call the above `verify` method.

   ```
   import random

   orig = list(range(20))
   for i in range(100):  # repeat a few times with different shuffles of input
       values = orig[:]
       random.shuffle(values)
       heap  = MaxMinHeap(len(values)+3)  # Allocate enough space for the heap
       for value in values:  # Insert the values in their shuffled order
           heap.insert_num(value)
           heap.verify()  # ... and each time verify all is well
   ```
4. If the above test turns out well (it does), continue with adding `min_output` calls in the test

   ```
   import random

   orig = list(range(20))
   for i in range(100):  # repeat a few times with different shuffles of input
       values = orig[:]
       random.shuffle(values)
       heap  = MaxMinHeap(len(values)+3)  # Allocate enough space for the heap
       for value in values:  # Insert the values in their shuffled order
           heap.insert_num(value)
           heap.verify()  # ... and each time verify all is well

       res = []  # output of values as they are removed from the heap
       while not heap.empty():
           res.append(heap.min_output())
           heap.verify()

       if res != orig:
           print(values)
           print("Removal was not in order", res)
           break
   ```

   This test failed! Reducing the size of the `orig` list to even just 4 values, it went wrong with a shuffled `values` like [3,1,0,2]. A great candidate to then drill down further into what is causing the inconsistency (see further).
5. You can continue with `max_output` tests in the same manner.
6. Once you find which state leads to an inconsistent heap, start debugging with a debugger stepping through the code, inspecting names, ...etc

I can only urge to not give up on an issue that quickly: designing tests like above is actually not that hard, and it helps you identify problems in a reasonable time.

### Conclusions

I found these issues in `minify_down`:

1. At several places you have `if .... == self.arr_len`, which excludes cases where the test index is actually *less than* that limit, while those indexes should be allowed to pass that test too. So change to `<=`.
2. There is a `self.heap_arr[comp_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index]` test, which obviously makes no sense. Intended was `self.heap_arr[comp_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index+1]`
3. The condition `temp_index + 1 == self.arr_len` should not only be corrected to use `<=` (point 1), but should be `temp_index <= self.arr_len`, since your intention is to access `self.heap_arr[temp_index]`, not `self.heap_arr[temp_index+1]`
4. Further down you perform a swap *without checking that this swap is needed*! So change that:

   ```
   self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if self.heap_arr[input_index] > self.heap_arr[comp_index]:
       self.heap_arr[input_index], self.heap_arr[comp_index] = self.heap_arr[comp_index], self.heap_arr[input_index]
   ```

With those changes the above test code will pass. Similar problems exist in `maxify_down` which you can correct along the same lines.